# Unexpected result for Groebner basis

Tags: mathematica, groebner-basis

I am trying to (re)compute the Groebner basis used for proving the theorem of Pappus (plane geometry) as done [here](http://ecrypt-ss07.rhul.ac.uk/Slides/Tuesday/buchberger-samos07.pdf) on pages 22-23. Since I have no Mathematica license, I used e.g. [REDUCE](http://reduce-algebra.com/):

```
load_package groebner;
f := {u3*u4-u2*u5-u3*u7+u5*u7+u2*x1-u4*x1, u5*x2-u4*x3, -u1*u2+u1*x2-u3*x2+u2*x3, x1*x4-u7*x5, -u2*u6-u3*x4+u6*x4+u2*x5, u1*u7-u1*x6+x1*x6-u7*x7, -u4*u6-u5*x6+u6*x6+u4*x7, 1-v*(x3*x4-x2*x5-x3*x6+x5*x6+x2*x7-x4*x7)};
groebner f;
```

But the result is not the expected `{1}`, it is a list of 70 polynomials. Similar results I get when using [Singular](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/).

I have double (triple, quadruple, ...) checked the input polynomials. Placing the "input" points at `A(0,0), B(0,u1=1), C(0,u6=5/2), A1(u2=1,u3=-1), B1(u4=2,u5=-1), C1(u7=3,x1=-1)`, s.t. the configuration looks like in the image below, I computed `P(x2=2/3,x3=-1/3), Q(x4=15/19,x5-5/19), S(x6=18/13,x7=1/13)`.

[image: Pappus theorem: A,B,C and A1,B1,C1 being collinear makes P,Q,S collinear]

When plugging these values into the input polynomials I get the expected "cancellations":

```
s := {u1=1, u6=5/2, u2=1, u3=-1, u4=2, u5=-1, u7=3, x1=-1, x2=2/3, x3=-1/3, x4=15/19, x5=-5/19, x6=18/13, x7=1/13};
sub(s, f);
     -->      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
```

The 7 `0`s come from the 7 given collinearities (the eighth collinearity of `A,B,C` is implicit by placing them on the y-axis), the `1` from the Rabinowitch trick (the factor of `v` for the concluded collinearity of `P,Q,S` is also `0`). I am stuck now. Am I missing something? Can someone verify the Groebner basis calculation in Mathematica? The input should be:

```
GroebnerBasis[{u3*u4-u2*u5-u3*u7+u5*u7+u2*x1-u4*x1,u5*x2-u4*x3,-u1*u2+u1*x2-u3*x2+u2*x3,x1*x4-u7*x5,-u2*u6-u3*x4+u6*x4+u2*x5,u1*u7-u1*x6+x1*x6-u7*x7,-u4*u6-u5*x6+u6*x6+u4*x7,1-v*(x3*x4-x2*x5-x3*x6+x5*x6+x2*x7-x4*x7)},{u1,u2,u3,u4,u5,u6,u7,v,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7}]
```

Comment: What exactly are the variables, and what are only parameters? I can compute it then and we can compare.

Comment: Can you use the same math packages to obtain a solution of the polynomial system and then recover what are the points?

Comment: @DietrichBurde `u1,...,u7` and `x1,...,x7` are coordinates. I have taken over the naming from the referenced source. `v` is the Rabinovitch parameter. But when it comes to Groebner basis computation, they are all variables, I think; no distinction except for their lexicographic order.

Comment: All right. Then our results are correct. You can easily shorten these polynomial solutions by considering certain subcases, by the way. Then you don't have to view $70$ polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations obviously have a lot of trivial solutions, for example,
$$
vx_4(x_3- x_7) = 1,\; u_6=u_3, \quad u_4=u_2=x_2=x_6=u_7=x_1=0.
$$
So the set of equations is perhaps not correct. So far we don't obtain any contradiction, i.e., the Groebner basis is not equal to $\{1\}$, and Reduce is fine (and for free).

Comment: The equations by themselves are correct - but obviously not sufficient to prove the theorem.

Comment: More equations (for avoiding singularities) seem to be necessary. They are not mentioned in the referenced source.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for pointing out this (mostly) trivial solution. As long as solutions exist, the preconditions of the theorem to prove cannot be complete.

Comment: For the downvoter - The question was, whether or not Reduce or Singular was faulty, and that we should try Mathematica. The answer here is no, and then a trivial solution is enough. Of course, one can write down all solutions, too. But this was not the question.